# On line integral $\displaystyle\int_{a + i\infty}^{a - i\infty} \frac{\zeta^2(1-s)\zeta^2(s-4m-1)}{2 \cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)} \,\mathrm{d}s$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

I am curious on how one can evaluate the integral

$$\int_{a + i\infty}^{a - i\infty} \frac{\zeta^2(1-s)\zeta^2(s-4m-1)}{2 \cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)} \,\mathrm{d}s$$

where $4m+2<a< 4m+3$ and $m \in \mathbb{N}$.

I think I should be pushing the contour left and collect poles as I move. Basically I am looking for a series representation of the line integral of the form $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n)$ if it exists. I am wondering whether the integral will be zero on horizontal strips as I move down. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Assuming $a\in\mathbb{R}$, the integration is along a horizontal line. What do you mean by "whether the integral will be zero on vertical strips as I move down"?

Comment: Your integral diverges. Did you mean $a\pm i\infty$ ?

Comment: Also is $m$ an integer ?

Comment: The integral over $(-\infty + i a, \infty + i a)$ diverges. The integral over $(a - i \infty, a + i \infty)$ for $m \in \mathbb Z$ is equal to
$$2 \pi i \cases {
\frac 1 {2 \pi} \sum_{k = 1}^{-2 m - 1} (-1)^k
 \zeta^2(2 k) \zeta^2(-4 m - 2 k)& $m < 0$ \\
\zeta(-1) \zeta'(-1) - \gamma \zeta^2(-1) - \frac 1 {32 \pi} & $m = 0$ \\
\zeta(-4 m - 1) \zeta'(-4 m - 1) - \gamma \zeta^2(-4 m - 1) & $m > 0$
}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functional equation $\zeta(1-s) = {2\over (2\pi)^s}\,\cos\left(\frac{\pi s}2\right)\,\Gamma(s)\,\zeta(s)$ gives that **your integral diverges** due to the growth of $\Gamma(ai+t)$ as $t\to +\infty$.

If instead you meant $a\pm i\infty$ and $m\in \Bbb{Z}$ then letting $f(s)=\frac{\zeta^2(1-s)\zeta^2(s-4m-1)}{2 \cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)}$

$$I=\int_{a -i\infty}^{a + i\infty} f(s)\,\mathrm{d}s$$
The change of variable $s=4m+2-z$ gives
$$I = \int_{4m+2-a+ i\infty}^{4m+2-a -i \infty} f(4m+2-z) \,\mathrm{d}(4m+2-z)
= -\int_{4m+2-a - i\infty}^{4m+2-a +i \infty} f(z) \,\mathrm{d}z
$$
On the other hand, the residue theorem and that $\zeta(-2k)=0$ gives for $m\ge 1$

$$I=\int_{4m+2-a -i\infty}^{4m+2-a + i\infty} f(s) \,\mathrm{d}s
 +2i\pi Res(f(s),0)+2i\pi Res(f(s),4m+2)$$

whence $$I = i\pi Res(f(s),0)+i\pi Res(f(s),4m+2)$$
Since $f(s)=-f(4m+2-s)$ and $Res(f(s),4m+2)=-Res(f(4m+2-s),0)$
we get that $I=2i\pi Res(f(s),0)$